# Tomcat downloading zipped jar files not working

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, download, zip

I wrote a Tomcat Servlet for downloading files.
This is the code:

```
String fileName = request.getParameter("file");
File file = new File(System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME") + File.separator + fileName);

response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
long written = FileUtils.copyFile(file, out);
out.flush();

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(written + " bytes written in " + (end - start) + "ms");
```

I download a file using Firefox (localhost:8080/download?file=test.txt).
In almost all cases, the broser immediately shows the download-dialog, and the server-console shows "4342132 bytes written in 118ms".

But whenever I want to download a .zip file which contains .jar files, it takes up to 20 seconds until the browser shows the download-dialog. Sometimes, the download is event aborted. But the server-log shows "4883055 bytes written in 129ms".

When I use .zip files without .jar files in it, everything works fine. How is that possible????

It´s not a Firefox specific problem. The problem occurs in any browser (FF, Chrome, Opera, ...).

Comment: It's not a very good idea to store your files in Tomcat's home directory; your webapp should have its own working directory, outside the webapp directory itself at that. Also, use JSR 203 and not `File`: this is 2015.

Comment: @fge it´s just for testing. Not for production.